# does a for loop have to have a code of execution inside the loop to be considered o(n)?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

```
function doNothing(n) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++);
}
```

Does a for loop that does nothing count as O(n)? Or would this be constant time?

Answer (score 1):

The for loop doesn't "do nothing", it increments the variable `i` by one on each iteration five times. This is of course ignoring the fact a compiler may choose to remove this code completely.

So the for loop `for (let i = 0; i < n; i++);` is O(N). In your case however with `for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++);` since you do only five things, which is a constant amount of work, its O(1) (ie 5 ∈ O(1)) but remember this is because five is a constant not because the loop does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is constant time. As `i` will always run from `0 to 5`.

The time complexity of the above piece of code will be `O(1)`.